# Recursive directory download with Paramiko?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I want to download a directory with unknown contents recursively via SSH and have been trying Paramiko. I have seen several examples how to upload directories but none that covers recursive download.

I can list all items in a directory but haven't been able to find a way of knowing if the item is a file (to download) or a directory (to call recursively).

```
transport = paramiko.Transport((MY_IP, 22))
transport.connect(username=MY_NAME, password=MY_PASS)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)

file_list = sftp.listdir(path='/home/MY_HOME_DIR')
    for item in file_list:
        # Here is an item name... but is it a file or directory?
        print(item)
sftp.close()
transport.close()
```

So how do I know if an item is a file or if it is a directory?

Comment: Is using rsync an option? http://rsync.samba.org

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
from stat import S_ISDIR

def isdir(path):
  try:
    return S_ISDIR(sftp.stat(path).st_mode)
  except IOError:
    #Path does not exist, so by definition not a directory
    return False
```

...assuming `sftp` is an open Paramiko SFTP connection.

Comment: Can't test this now, but this seems to add the last missing piece into a complete answer. Moving accepted flag here.

Answer (score 4):

Paramiko does not support recursive operations.

But it's easy to implement:

```
import os
from stat import S_ISDIR, S_ISREG
```

```
def get_r_portable(sftp, remotedir, localdir):
    for entry in sftp.listdir_attr(remotedir):
        remotepath = remotedir + "/" + entry.filename
        localpath = os.path.join(localdir, entry.filename)
        mode = entry.st_mode
        if S_ISDIR(mode):
            try:
                os.mkdir(localpath)
            except OSError:     
                pass
            get_r_portable(sftp, remotepath, localpath)
        elif S_ISREG(mode):
            sftp.get(remotepath, localpath)
```

---

You also can use [pysftp](https://pypi.org/project/pysftp/). It's a wrapper around Paramiko that has more Python-ish look and feel and supports recursive operations.  See

- [`pysftp.Connection.put_r()`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook.html#pysftp-connection-put-r)
- [`pysftp.Connection.get_r()`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook.html#pysftp-connection-get-r)

Or see my answer to [Python pysftp get_r from Linux works fine on Linux but not on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50118919/850848#50130813).

But pysftp seems to be an abandoned project, so you better stick with Paramiko.

Answer (score 3):

An old question, but a solution I came up with that works quite well, it's a little bit sloppy (typecasting and slashes and all) - but it does work.

Note this uses `fabric.api.local` to make the directories in the destination.

```
def sftp_get_recursive(path, dest, sftp=sftp):
    item_list = sftp.listdir(path)
    dest = str(dest)

    if not os.path.isdir(dest):
        local("mkdir %s" % dest)

    for item in item_list:
        item = str(item)

        if is_directory(path + "/" + item, sftp):
            sftp_get_recursive(path + "/" + item, dest + "/" + item, sftp)
        else:
            sftp.get(path + "/" + item, dest + "/" + item)
```

Comment: This answer as per 2021 requires a few updates; I posted the updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

A small update to Dan LaManna's answer that works in 2021.

```
import paramiko
import os
from stat import S_ISDIR, S_ISREG    

def sftp_get_recursive(path, dest, sftp):
    item_list = sftp.listdir_attr(path)
    dest = str(dest)
    if not os.path.isdir(dest):
        os.makedirs(dest, exist_ok=True)
    for item in item_list:
        mode = item.st_mode
        if S_ISDIR(mode):
            sftp_get_recursive(path + "/" + item.filename, dest + "/" + item.filename, sftp)
        else:
            sftp.get(path + "/" + item.filename, dest + "/" + item.filename)

transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
transport.connect(username=username, password=password)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
sftp_get_recursive(remote_path, local_path, sftp)
sftp.close()
```

Comment: By direct use of low-level `Transport` class, this solution bypasses host key verification, so it is susceptible to MITM attacks. For functionally equivalent, but safe code, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6674862/850848#53556194).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the stat() method of your sftp object:

http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.SFTPClient-class.html

Comment: Ah yes, that might be it. Haven't tested it yet but with a bit of luck the directory flag can be parsed out of SFTPAttributes.st_mode. Now I just need to research what flags are hidden in that mode value...

Answer (score 1):

stat() method among other attributes returns permissions. d (for example drwxrwxrwx) shows that it is directory.

As example:

```
dir = oct(sftp.stat(path).st_mode)
print dir[0:2]
```

output interpritation:
01 fifo 
02 character special 
04 directory 
06 block special 
10 regular file 
12 symbolic link 
14 socket

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer for 2022.

[pysftp](https://pypi.org/project/pysftp/) is abandoned. [paramiko](https://pypi.org/project/paramiko/) does not implement recursivity for SFTP. So I made a library named [sftputil](https://pypi.org/project/sftputil/) (to make a parallel with [ftputil](https://pypi.org/project/ftputil/)) based on Paramiko.

[sftputil](https://pypi.org/project/sftputil/) implements functionalities such as `walk`, `glob` and `sync`. To copy an entire directory, the easiest way is to use the synchronization feature :

```py
from sftputil import SFTP

sftp = SFTP("hostname", "username", password="password")

# To copy recursively
sftp.sync_pull("remote/path", "local/dir")

# To copy only the files
sftp.sync_pull("remote/path", "local/dir", recursive=False)
```

Answer (score -6):

If u using Linux or Unix-like. U can use 'file' utility with popen.
Or simple u can use os.path.isdir() =)

Comment: Proper english please. Besides that, using `file` to test if something is a folder or not is pretty messy. And using `os.path.isdir()` on a remote file..?