# Python: Copy the directory from remote machine(Linux/Windows) to local machine(Windows)

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, paramiko, pysftp

I am trying to copy a folder(Directory) from the remote machine to the local machine.

```
import paramiko
import os
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("IP", username="root", password="password")
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
remote_path = '/tmp/'
local_path = 'D:\\Test\\tmp'
sftp.get(remote_path, local_path)
```

But, the problem I am facing is, I am unable to copy the entire folder. 
Can someone suggest me the modules which I can use for copying the entire directory from remote linux/Windows machine to local windows machine.

Comment: Particularly see, [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6674862/850848#53556194) (posted just now) and the answer by [@DanLaManna](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6674862/850848#15932241).

Comment: Also see [Python pysftp get_r from Linux works fine on Linux but not on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50118919/850848).