# How to validate generated remote files against standard set of files and dirs?

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko

A Directory containing set of files, sub-dir and sub-dir containing files, I need to check whether these files are actually 
generated on remote location.

say `[a.log,b.log,c.log,tmp_folder]` and `tmp_folder` containing `d.log,e.log` files

Currently, I'm logging into remote machine and getting list of files but I'm unable to match these and also I'm unable to sftp that entire directory to local machine.

```
remote_dir = "some/location/path/time_stamp_10101010"
local_dir = "location/on/local/path"
```

Need to copy that entire directory `time_stamp_10101010` in `local_path`.

```
import re,os,sys
import paramiko


remote_dir = "some/location/path/time_stamp_10101010"
local_dir = "location/on/local/path" 

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(host_ip, username=username,key_filename=key_filename,port=22)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("ls")
sftp_client = ssh.open_sftp()
dir_items = sftp_client.listdir_attr(remote_dir)
for item in dir_items:
    print item
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(remote_dir, item)):
            remote_path = remote_dir + '/' + item.filename
            local_path = os.path.join(local_dir, item.filename)
            sftp_client.put_dir(remote_path, local_path)
    # If item is a directory here and if it contains sub-directory and files
    # How can I implement to copy recursively till all sub-directories and files are included.
```

Am I doing it right ? or Is there any better apparoach ?
How do i validate the files, sub-dirs generated in a directory matches the standard set (as mentioned above) ? reg-ex would be better i feel.

Comment: See my answer to [Recursive directory download with Paramiko?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53556194/850848).

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive function like this:

```
def recursive_walk(path, remote_directory="", local_directory=""):
    if os.path.isfile(path):
        print("I am a file take me anywhere", path)

        return
    for item in os.listdir(path):
        item_path = os.path.join(path, item)
        recursive_walk(item_path)


recursive_walk('.')
```