# Get Recursive folder using SFTP and Paramiko Python

Tags: python, paramiko, pysftp

Trying to implement a python script to  and put get recursive folder from remote machine to local machine , this code works for copy : put folders and get folders , now i want to create move , the idea is to remove file once transfered i add line sftp.remove() and get the error stack at the end of the post any clue guys ?

```
import paramiko
    import os
    from stat import S_ISDIR, S_ISREG  
    
    class MySFTPClient(paramiko.SFTPClient):
            def put_dir(self, source, target):
                    ''' Uploads the contents of the source directory to the target path. The
                        target directory needs to exists. All subdirectories in source are 
                        created under target.
                    '''
                    for item in os.listdir(source):
                        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(source, item)):
                            self.put(os.path.join(source, item), '%s/%s' % (target, item))
                        else:
                            self.mkdir('%s/%s' % (target, item), ignore_existing=True)
                            self.put_dir(os.path.join(source, item), '%s/%s' % (target, item))
    
            def mkdir(self, path, mode=511, ignore_existing=False):
                    ''' Augments mkdir by adding an option to not fail if the folder exists  '''
                    try:
                        super(MySFTPClient, self).mkdir(path, mode)
                    except IOError:
                        if ignore_existing:
                            pass
                        else:
                            raise
    
    def sftp_get_recursive(path, dest, sftp):
            item_list = sftp.listdir_attr(path)
            dest = str(dest)
            if not os.path.isdir(dest):
                os.makedirs(dest, exist_ok=True)
            for item in item_list:
                mode = item.st_mode
                if S_ISDIR(mode):
                    sftp_get_recursive(path + "/" + item.filename, dest + "/" + item.filename, sftp)
                else:
                    sftp.get(path + "/" + item.filename, dest + "/" + item.filename)
                    print("Removing file :",item.filename)
                    sftp.remove(dest + "/" + item.filename)
```

> > Solved by changing  sftp.remove(dest + "/" + item.filename) to sftp.remove(path + "/" + item.filename)

```
    transport = paramiko.Transport(('172.31.11.233', 22))
    transport.connect(username='$(ops_unv_cred_user_018f3e16e789465bb5110a90837ce03f)', password='$(ops_unv_cred_pwd_018f3e16e789465bb5110a90837ce03f)')
      
    if 1==1:
        sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)            
        if 0==1:
            sftp.get('/home/karim/EDV','/home/karim/israel')
            print("copied successfully!")                      
        else:
            sftp_get_recursive('/home/karim/EDV', '/home/karim/israel', sftp)
            print("copied successfully!")
            if 1==1:
                print("Listing all files in remote machine where path is => /home/karim/EDV :" )
                print(sftp.listdir('/home/karim/EDV'))
        if 1==1: 
            print("Listing all files in remote machine where path is => /home/karim/EDV :" )
            print(sftp.listdir('/home/karim/EDV'))       
    else:
        sftp = MySFTPClient.from_transport(transport) 
        if 0==1: 
            sftp.put('/home/karim/israel','/home/karim/EDV')
            print("copied successfully!")
           
        else:        
            sftp.mkdir('/home/karim/EDV', ignore_existing=True)
            sftp.put_dir('/home/karim/israel','/home/karim/EDV')
            print("copied successfully!")
    
        if 1==1:   
            print("Listing all files in remote machine where path is => /home/karim/EDV :" )
            print(sftp.listdir('/home/karim/EDV'))
    
    sftp.close()



Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/karim/.56ee3cce-0616-4070-bfa5-b5a0f346b2c7.sh", line 64, in <module>
    sftp_get_recursive('/home/karim/EDV', '/home/karim/israel', sftp)   File "/home/karim/.56ee3cce-0616-4070-bfa5-b5a0f346b2c7.sh", line 50, in sftp_get_recursive
    sftp_get_recursive(path + "/" + item.filename, dest + "/" + item.filename, sftp)   File "/home/karim/.56ee3cce-0616-4070-bfa5-b5a0f346b2c7.sh", line 54, in sftp_get_recursive
    sftp.remove(dest + "/" + item.filename)   File "/opt/universal/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 398, in remove
    self._request(CMD_REMOVE, path)   File "/opt/universal/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 813, in _request
    return self._read_response(num)   File "/opt/universal/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 865, in _read_response
    self._convert_status(msg)   File "/opt/universal/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 894, in _convert_status
    raise IOError(errno.ENOENT, text) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, it seems that the `target` is a remote path, although it should be "source", as you are downloading. And you are using the remote path with local API like `os.listdir`. That cannot work, you should use `SFTPClient.listdir_attr`.

For an example of working recursive download, see:
[Recursive directory download with Paramiko?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6674862/850848#53556194)